# Конвертация синтаксиса кода

Tags: c#

Есть задача объединить исходники библиотеки в один файл и при этом преобразовать код, написанный на C# 7.0 в C# 4.0.

Есть ли возможность сделать конвертацию кода автоматически, чтобы не пришлось все править вручную?